# Stringbuilder - Replacing all instances of one character with another**

Tags: scala, junit, stringbuilder

First time posting on here, let me know if I need to change my format and I will do so.

I need to extract a defined region from the buffer, and apply code that will substitute character 'x' with character 'y', which I have attempted below:

```
buffer.substring(lwr,upr).replace(s,t)
```

However that fails all of my JUNIT tests and I can't wrap my head around why.

Does anybody have any pointers? Thank you!

EDIT:

For example, given the following:

```
a p p r o p r i a t e      (Marker position is 2, cursor position is 6)
   ^       ^
```

Doing "subChar('p', 'x') should result in this being the output:

```
a p x r o x r i a t e      (Marker position and cursor position DO NOT CHANGE)
   ^       ^
```

Comment: What is your junit test? It's either your code is wrong or junit is wrong

Comment: I have multiple tests for this function, however this is one of them:

@Test def test_sc_65 {
    val buf: Buffer = new Buffer(word)
    import buf._
    dr; tr; sc('a','X')
    assertEquals("XXrdvXrk", getString)
    assertEquals("", getPaste)
  }

Comment: ...so you took exactly the same title of the answered (abandoned) question, even though it does not describe your problem in any way?

Comment: I just noticed this, my bad. I was planning on making 2 posts (one for each question I had) however I typed the body on the wrong tab.

Comment: what is getString and getPaste? The issue, as stated in one of the answers, probably stems from the fact that doing substring won't modify the original stringbuilder, so maybe you could pass that 'sc' command directly into your assert? or maybe writing a function that will manually change `s` to `t` from `lwr` to `upr`

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is your Buffer, I created a ScalaFiddle that demonstrates it for simple String and a simple List implementation:

```
val str = "appropriate"

println (str.replace('p', 'x')) // axxroxriate

val list = str.toList.map{
  case c if c == 'p' => 'x'
  case c => c
} 

println (list) // List(a, x, x, r, o, x, r, i, a, t, e)
```

Check your implementation or add your implementation to your question.

Here is the example with a region:

```
def replaceBetween(str: String, start: Int, end: Int, what: Char, byWhat: Char): String = {
  val prefix = str.take(start)
  val postfix = str.drop(end)
  val toMap = str.drop(start).take(end-start).replace(what, byWhat)

  prefix + toMap + postfix
}

println(replaceBetween("appropriate", 2, 6, 'p', 'x'))
```

**Here you can try yourself: [ScalaFiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/QHav20I/0)**

Comment: You are mapping the whole string, without the "defined region"-part. What happened to the marker position and the cursor?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a string, then substring something, then invoke `replace` on the result, the resulting string will have nothing to do with the original string, thus your solution obviously cannot work.

The indexing scheme from the linked answer remains the same, the answer is easily generalizable to arbitrary functions that can be applied to characters:

```
def mapBetween(str: String, start: Int, end: Int)(f: Char => Char) = { 
  val (a, bc) = str.splitAt(start)
  val (b, c) = bc.splitAt(end - start)
  a + b.map(f) + c 
}

def replaceBetween(str: String, start: Int, end: Int, what: Char, byWhat: Char): String = {
  mapBetween(str, start, end){ c =>
    if (c == what) byWhat else c
  }
}
```

With the above definitions, this here:

```
println(replaceBetween("appropriate", 2, 6, 'p', 'x'))
```

produces:

```
apxroxriate
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I did see this, however I'm struggling to apply this to my case, as I'm not using anything like "println", as this is being used in the case of JUnit testing, as apposed to just a regular function.

Comment: @MichaelCoe And what's the difference? Are the methods in JUnit test-suite somehow "irregular"? The `replaceBetween` method is just a static method like any other. It does not care where you use it.